# Averaging methods to deal with overlapping time series

Tags: time-series, distributions, overlapping-data

Consider the scenario where one is trying to fit a distribution to historical yearly excess returns of an equity index (say S&P 500 excess return over T bills). Monthly data are available but we aim to fit the yearly excess returns (and not monthly returns). There are many resources with how to deal with overlapping data, e.g. [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/740/time-series-regression-with-overlapping-data), [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17441/empirical-distribution-function-of-overlapping-time-series-data), ..., and the linked resources.

However, in all the resources I find I do not see the following approach discussed: split the data set into 12 non-overlapping data sets. Fit 12 distributions separately on the non-overlapping data. Then use the mixture of these 12 distributions as the final distribution (or fit another more simpler distribution to the mixture distribution if one does not want to use such a complex characterization).

My questions:

1. Are there some obvious reasons why this is a terrible idea?
2. Are then any resources that discuss this approach (or an approach which is similar)?

Comment: Migrated after OP request.